# Command not found selenium python visual code

Tags: python, selenium, visual-studio-code

To find the exact path of the email I used this command `email = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id="iLogin"]")`.
The problem is that this command is not found despite that the selenium is well installed. Note that only the "`find_element` command" that works others commands (id, name, linktext, Xpath) not available.

attached the screenshot vs code[test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZBOZ.png)

Comment: ok well received, I didn't find the solution I simply updated the python and selenium version: p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import below library. [Selenium Doc](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```